# what does mean by lose your phone?

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

I was watching a series of video about English teaching, I heard a word like lose your phone, I am not sure that whether the word is right or not,  thanks everyone for helping me.
Does anyone say to others  like hanging up your phone, could say lose your phone, they are the same expression?

Comment: Please link to the video and indicate the approximate time at which you think you hear the phrase.

Comment: Is there a place uploading the video from my disk?

Comment: Probably, but I don't know how to do so. If it were a website, you could copy the url.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways "lose" might have been used in your case.

Question: Did you lose your phone?

Or

Telling someone to throw away their phone. Lose your phone. May be it was bugged by the FBI.

In the second case, "lose" means to "cease to have or retain (something)". Lose the murder weapon before your car is searched. This means throw it away.

You could also tell someone "Lose him" when you are in a car with "someone" and "him" is chasing you in in their car. This would mean "evade or shake off (a pursuer)".

Lose: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lose

Comment: You can also “lose a call” or “lose signal.”   The call ends because your phone has a poor connection.    (You can also lose a call if the other person loses signal.)

Comment: Thanks for the addition. Also, people often say "Don't lose it", as in 'temper'.

Comment: So what is the reason this got a downvote?